# Topology of solution to a nonlinear eigenvalue problem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, harmonic-functions, laplacian

Consider the elliptic PDE:

$$-\Delta u= f(x) u. $$

Assume that $f,u$ are defined in some reasonable bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and impose the boundary condition $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega.$

Suppose first $f\equiv \lambda \in \mathbb{R}.$ Then is a fact that there are infinitely many, discrete choices of $\lambda$ such that this equation holds.

I want to know more generally about the structure of the set of $f$ which admit solutions to the above equation.

In particular, is the set of  $f$ such that the above equation holds "exceptional" in any sense?

E.g. could the following statement be true?  "for any $f \in C^0(\Omega)$ which admits a solution to the above equation, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that if $\|g-f\|_{C^0} < \epsilon$ and $g$ also admits a solution to the equation then $f \equiv g.$"

(N.B. I am actually interested in the case where $f,u$ are defined on a closed manifold and $\Delta$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator, but I have asked the question in the Euclidean setting since I assume this is more familiar to most people.)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the equation $-\Delta u = f(x) u$ is *linear*; why then is this question titled " . . . *nonlinear* eigenvalue problem"?  Just curious.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis I was under the impression that a "nonlinear e-value problem" refers to an e-value problem where the unknown is a function rather than a scalar. But I agree that the equation is linear... Feel free to modify the title if my terminology is wrong.

Comment: Well, you may be right; I guess my thoughts to this point are that it's really a question about how solutions to the equation $(\Delta + f)u = 0$ behave as we try to vary $f$, which being a function is not exactly an *eigenvalue* in the classical sense.  Don't have an immediate answer.  To my mind, it's more about the operator.   Nice question, though; ***endorsed!***

Answer (score 0):

Robert Lewis has the right line.  $fu$ is a multiplication operator (and is self-adjoint).  If $f$ is bounded, then $\Delta+f$ is bounded and self-adjoint so it has a spectral decomposition.  The decomposition varies continuously with $f$, no?  That is, the only way for it to be the same is if $f$ and $g$ differ on a set of measure zero?